# Applying Css classes to any html element with help of css

Tags: css

hello my simple question is that with the help of css can we apply css classes to any html element which have no class on it or with the help of css (targeting ) can we add any class to an html element.

For E.g `<div class="style1" id="any"> hi  </div>`

Is there any way to add a class on this div using id or by any means??

Can we do this?

`div.style1` `addclass('new');` ?

Note: I want to add class just using css. I can add using Javascript

Comment: No, and it doesn't make any sense. Why not add it directly in your markup?

Comment: _I can add using JavaScript_. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do it with just CSS since CSS can't change the document,
CSS deals only with instructing the browser how the elements should look.

If you want to apply the styles of class `new` to all the elements `div.style1` then you can use change your class styles

```
.new {
    /* styles */
}
```

to something like

```
.new, div.style1 {
    /* styles */
}
```

and, from the CSS point of view, the result will be the same as with the behaviour you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create this using jQuery.

> $('.style1').addClass('new');

Comment: I typed a note that I am aware of Jquery or Javascript way of adding class I was askin if this we can do by CSS?